# How to force armbian create an AP with 2.4 GHz instead of 5 GHz?

Tags: wifi-configuration, armbian

Orange Pi 3. Armbian-config creates a hotspot for Wi-Fi 5 GHz on channel 40 and sometimes on 2.4 GHz. I know it scanning for better, but I need to always create 2.4 GHz Wi-FI AP. If I'm just changing channel from 40 to 6 AP doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/hostapd.conf` and locate the `#IEEE 802.11` section. Then, comment all of the uncommented lines. For example:

```
### IEEE 802.11n
## ieee80211n=1
## ht_capab=[DSSS_CK-40][HT20+]
## country_code=US
## ieee80211d=1
## IEEE 802.11n

## IEEE 802.11a
## hw_mode=a
## IEEE 802.11a

### IEEE 802.11ac
# ieee80211ac=1
# vht_capab=
# vht_oper_chwidth=1
# vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
### IEEE 802.11ac
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the right direction.
Whan I comment out everything that you wrote, then there is no Wi-Fi at all.
However, 2.4GHz goes up when I only commented out the lines
`ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=smth
hw_mode=a`
and set **channel to 6** instead of **40**.

Answer (score 0):

I set channel to 3 (another 2.4G channel also will work). Then I commented `hw_mode=a` and `ieee80211ac=1`.

As the attached figure suggests.

[image: figure]